# Are there any security implications of serving a page over HTTP on the same domain, but different port, as a service served over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, cross-domain

If I have an HTML page served over HTTP at `http://example.com:123`, and another served over HTTPS at `https://example.com:456/some_app`, is there any risk to the HTTPS app? Note that the following mitigations are assumed to be in place:

- The HTTP page is entirely unauthenticated and contains public information
- The cookies for the HTTPS page are marked `secure`
- The HTTPS page uses a standard anti-CSRF patter such as double submit

The main risk that I see is that an attacker could intercept the HTTP request and send back a page with malicious Javascript. While this is undesirable, I can't see any way that the attack could escalate. Despite the the overly permissive access controls on cookies, the attacker should not be able to steal the HTTPS page's cookies, because they are marked secure. As far as cross origin requests go, requests made by the HTTP page are considered as coming from a different origin, so the CSRF protections work there.

Are there any attack venues that I'm missing? Or is the HTTPS app reasonably safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secure" attribute of cookies prevents the cookies being **sent** with a http request so they are only sent with https. However there is nothing to prevent javascript on the http page **reading** the cookie if, for example, it has been tampered with either in transit to include extra javascript or was vulnerable to a XSS flaw.

This could be remediated by setting the HttpOnly flag as well as the secure flag but that will may not work for your Double protection CSRF implementation if JavaScript is needed to read the cookie.

EDIT: Comments below state that Chrome (at least) prevents this when Secure flag is set but I cannot see this explicitly called out in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) and in fact section 8.5 states that cookies do not always follow the same restrictions for scheme and path when accessed through document.cookie. It also gives the example of path restrictions being ignored when accessed locally using document.cookie - though admittedly doesn't explicitly mention whether Secure cookies can be read from javascript on non-https pages. I would err on the cautious side and so assume they are not secure from javascript on http pages unless HttpOnly flag is set.

The other issue is that there is nothing to stop the Http page **setting** the cookie, and overwriting the existing one. Again this could be achieved by intercepting the http page response and adding a Set-Cookie header, or by using javascript on the page of vulnerable to XSS. While you might think overwriting a cookie wouldn't cause too many problems it could log you in as someone else for example without the person realising at which point they might enter other private data under this incorrect login.

Of course your https page could also be vulnerable to XSS too but the interception attacks mention are only an issue on unsecured http (and I'm including poorly configured https in that btw). Additionally http pages are typically handled with less care by users and developers alike and also load insecure third party content without error. So could be more vulnerable to XSS or other issues.

This is not to mention the fact that, with only a port number difference, your http site could be intercepted and made to look like your https site as a phishing site in the hope your visitors are happy with the server name and don't notice the incorrect port.

And those are just a few issues I can think of.

I would strongly advise not allowing http and https on the same server name, would suggest https everywhere and even go as far as recommending HSTS to ensure this.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your first statement? At least in Chrome, if I type `document.cookie = "test_secure_key=test_secure_value;secure"` in the console of an HTTP page, I can not read that cookie back from `document.cookie`. If I reload the page via HTTPS, I can read that cookie

Comment: The RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) is not clear on this point and concentrates on the transport side rather than on the local reading of cookies. Section 8.5 does state "Cookies do not always provide isolation by path. Although the network-level protocol does not send cookies stored for one path to another, some user agents expose cookies via non-HTTP APIs, such as HTML's document.cookie API. <snip> ...a resource retrieved from one path might be able to access cookies stored for another path." Chrome's implementation makes sense but I wouldn't be 100% confident others restrict this.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the uncertainty around that risk - which still leaves it open as a risk in my mind :-)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the update. I should have known never to take one browser's implementation as the standard